# I Need a Lightweight Version Management System for Word, PDF, and Zip Files

Tags: version-control

I am building a system that will allow users to upload Word, PDF, and Zip files.

Sometimes, they will review those files and upload newer versions. I will need to keep the older versions too, as they would also like to have the ability to download them.

Instead of storing all versions in full, I would rather store the first versions,  and diffs for the successive versions. Basically, I need to store all versions of a document in the smallest possible space. (Maybe it can be done in a different way, without diffs?).

There is no need for merging changes, multi-user, distributed, or any advanced features that typically come with version control systems. All use of the tool will be made through my application.

Is there an easy-to-learn, lightweight, open-source package, with good JVM (or REST) interoperability, that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No needs for reinventing the wheels.

JavaHL or SVNKit will allow you to work with Subversion repositories from Java